# 403 error permission error

Tags: php, apache

I open a apache server on my PC. And I can visit it by http://localhost. When I went to cmd and use ipconfig to know my ip and try to visit the site by this ip, it's failed.

```
"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.17 Server at 169.243.***.** Port 80"
```

How can I solve this problem? I want to use my phone to visit it and download some files. btw, my PC and phone were in the same network.
Thanks!

Comment: What results did your own search bring up? What did you try, what didn't work? Be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have

```
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
```

Somewhere in your httpd.conf or your .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you chmod'd your www directory to 775 if you are on linux
  (Should be by default, but just in case you have some weird `umask`
  set).
- Make sure you have index.php inside your www directory
- Make sure that `Options -Indexes` is in your .htaccess if you intend 
  to show directory listing